# How to change the default directory of msi log file?

Tags: wix

Can I change the default directory (%Temp%) of msi log file?

I want to move the log directory to ProgramData folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is, that the related property [`MsiLogFileLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370321(v=vs.85).aspx) is read-only, i.e. you have no chance to change the location of the logfile **within** a Windows Installer package.
There are some alternatives though:

- You can define the location of the logfile if you run the Windows Installer with the [`/L`-parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx), e.g. `msiexec.exe /i MyPackage.msi /l*v "C:\path\to\log\logfile.log"`
- To ensure that e.g. a customer will invoke this with the correct parameters you would have to create a bootstrapper around your MSI-file, using e.g. [`burn`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)
- Still another, more simple solution (that I used myself) would be: let the Windows Installer log the whole installation process to wherever it needs to. As you always have access to the complete path of the created logfile using the `MsiLogFileLocation`-property, simply copy the logfile as last step in your installation process to wherever you want to. The only drawback here: sometimes the last lines are missing as it is copied before the installation finished completely.

So if the very last lines are not always important (because you parse the logfile further etc.), the last solution would probably be the most simple one.
I scheduled it after `InstallFinalize` (and used the condition `NOT (REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)`, btw, else it overwrote or copied too much or... (can't remember)).

Comment: My conclusion was the third option you mentioned with the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Using what @taffit said above, this is what we ended up with:

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="ewiac!" />

<CustomAction Id="CopyLog" Execute="immediate"
          ExeCommand="cmd /c echo F|xcopy /y [MsiLogFileLocation] C:\ProgramData\scrpt\logs\scrpt-install.log &amp;&amp; del [MsiLogFileLocation]" 
          Directory="TARGETDIR" 
          Impersonate="yes" 
          Return="asyncNoWait" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyLog" After="InstallFinalize">NOT (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The xcopy was used because the log folder might not exist and copy won't create it.

The 'echo F|' pipes an F to the command when it asks if the destination is a file or directory.
The && indicates to do the following command if the first one worked